# SyntaxError: missing } after function body, one server good, live server fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

I can't figure out what is happening, I have this staging site http://eggsfruits.techqueb.com/midi.php were i did put tabs code and javascript. It is doing the process A1, when i upload my file to my live server http://www.eggsfruits.ca/midi.php the tabs does not work anymore and I get the error

> SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Can you please give me an hand on finding my issue

Comment: Sounds like a javascript issue. Users will need to see the code to assist.

Comment: as we can't see the actual source code of the `midi.php` file any answer would be speculative

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It would really improve the quality of the question when you include the code and pinpoint in which part of it is not working or you are having a problem. It would also improve the chances that your question will receive a quality answer.

Comment: looks like something is making the code inside the script tag all one line ... a poor minifier? ... which means everything after the first comment is regarded as a comment, hence the error

Comment: you forget to close javascript/jquery function. you need to add **});** to the end of your javascript/jquery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e){var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');// Show/Hide Tabs jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide(); // Change/remove current tab to active jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); e.preventDefault(); });
```

as you can see, you didnt close the function because you commend it.

so i think your code should be like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e){var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href'); });// Show/Hide Tabs jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide(); // Change/remove current tab to active jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: You are right did not think of that because on 1 site it was working and the other one note.

Comment: Thanks for the help